# URLClassLoader keeps throwing ClassNotFoundException. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, classloader, classnotfoundexception, urlclassloader

I'm working on a university java project that requires me to implement a simple plugin architecture. A main application in Project A would have to load plugins from a specified directory located in another project B. After having done some research on the topic (including stackoverflow), I decided to go with URLClassLoader to load the classes which I might then instatiate. Project B references Project A and all plugins extend a common plugin class (might as well be an interface but should not make any difference). This is what I have got so far:

The source for the plugin class I try to load:

```
package plugin;

import de.uks.student.pluginpattern.model.EditorPlugin;

public class Circle extends EditorPlugin
{
   @Override
   public void init()
   {

   }
}
```

and the code that is supposed to load the class:

```
public void init(String[] args)
   {
      editorPane = new EditorPane().withWidth(500).withHeight(500);
      toolBar = new ToolBar();
      plugins = new EditorPluginSet();
      // load plugins
      File pluginDir = new File(PLUGIN_PATH);
      if (!pluginDir.exists())
      {
         System.err.println("Plugin path not found!!");
         return;
      }
      String[] plugins = pluginDir.list();
      if (plugins == null)
      {
         System.err.println("Plugin path points to a file!!");
         return;
      }

      for (String pluginString : plugins)
      {
         for (String argString : args)
         {
            if (pluginString.contains(argString))
            {
               System.out.println("Loading plugin from " + pluginString);
               File pluginFile = new File(PLUGIN_PATH + "/");
               // as getAbsolutePath embeds the relative path ... /../pluginProject ...
               // which may not be processed correctly by the OS (Windows at least),
               // we correct the path manually (just to be on the safe side)
               String absolutePath = pluginFile.getAbsolutePath();
               String[] split = absolutePath.split("\\\\");

               List<String> splitsimpleList = Arrays.asList(split);
               ArrayList<String> splitList = new ArrayList<>(splitsimpleList);
               for (int i = 0; i < splitList.size() - 1; ++i)
               {
                  if (splitList.get(i + 1).equals(".."))
                  {
                     splitList.remove(i);
                     splitList.remove(i);
                     break;
                  }
               }
               StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
               for (String string : splitList)
               {
                  b.append(string);
                  b.append("/");
               }
               File pluginFileForRealThisTime = new File(b.toString());

               URL pluginURL = null;
               try
               {
                  pluginURL = pluginFileForRealThisTime.toURI().toURL();
               } catch (MalformedURLException e)
               {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }
               URL[] urls = {pluginURL};
               ClassLoader parentClassLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
               URLClassLoader uLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls, parentClassLoader);
               Class<?> pluginClass = null;
               try
               {
                  String className = "plugin." + argString;
                  pluginClass = uLoader.loadClass(className);
               } catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
               {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Now I always end up with a ClassNotFoundException:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: plugin.Circle   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   de.uks.student.pluginpattern.model.EditorSystem.init(EditorSystem.java:412)
>     at
>   de.uks.student.pluginpattern.EditorSystem.main(EditorSystem.java:13)

I've already checked that

- the generated URL can be correctly resolved by any web browser and Windows Explorer.
- Circle.class has been built and is present in the directory referenced by the used URL
- className resolves to "plugin.Circle" which should be the correct binary name to use
- removing inheritance from plugin.Circle does not make any difference.

I've pretty much run out of ideas on what else to try. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure that the file you're adding to the ClassLoader actually exists where you the it is, you can use File#exists to test this

Comment: And you should be able to use File#getCanonicalFile to get resolve relative paths to there "direct" path equivalent

Comment: Also, based on your code, you could be loading multiple Files, each in there own class loader, this could mean the class you're looking for might not exist within the file you have just loaded...

Comment: I got it to work! My mistake was to point the URLClassLoader to the plugin directory when I should have used the bin directory instead. Works now.

Comment: All that string manipulation looks really messy.  Does file.toURI().normalize().toURL() work?

Comment: @bkail: Yes it does. Thanks a lot, normalize() does exactly the same thing I do manually. Wasn't aware of it ...

Comment: Great to hear.  Anyway, I suggest adding your solution (the URL to a class loader must be the c:/classes/ directory rather than the c:/classes/plugin/ directory in order to load the "plugin.Circle" class from c:/classes/plugin/Circle.class), and then I think you can accept your own answer to "resolve" this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to point the ClassLoader to the bin folder instead of the bin/plugins folder